# I want to use Connection Pooling but my java application is not a servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, pooling

Part of my project is to enhance the thread-safety part of my application. I want to be able to store and retrieve data from a mysql database through JDBC Connector/J and I know that I need to use connection pooling for this but my application is not a servlet ... Should I still install Tomcat and change the config.xml file for the connection pooling datasource, connection numbers etc...?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a servlet or webapp to use db connection pooling. I'm sure there are a plenty of pools to use, my default is apache dbcp http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

To use dbcp you need to have the commons-dbcp-1.4.jar (for version 1.4) and the commons-pool (http://commons.apache.org/pool/) in your classpath.
A simple way to use pooling, is to use the [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ds.setUsername(username);
ds.setPassword(password);
ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
ds.setInitialSize(4);
```

Then, you can get connections out of the pool by calling `ds.getConnection()` .
Furthermore, you need to configure the maximum count of active connections, have a look at the [BasicDataSource API](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html).

Comment: Dear burna, I have visited that site many times and It doesn't seem to tell much about how to set up the connection pool for example which jar files ( if any is required ) should be installed or included in the CLASSPATH, or which files ( I mean config files if any) should be edited as needed... Do you know a simple way to start up with setting up a connection pool with apache dbcp? ... say any tutorial or smth? ...Still, most of the tutorials out there refer to Servlet development and mine is NOT ... its just a java application.

Comment: Dear burna, I have tried the apache commons dbcp and I seem not to be able to solve some errors that have to do with importing the right libraries from what apache provides as jars for dbcp to work...

Comment: dear all, I am using eclipse ganymede and I have included the commons-pool-1.6.jar in my CLASSPATH but still get some errors in importing the consequent libraries:                             import org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;            
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;                    Error says : The import org.apache.commons.dbcp cannot be resolved

Comment: I have now resolved the library issue and will go for a basicDataSource instead a pooledDataSource ... thank you @burna

Answer (score 0):

You can use c3p0 instead.

You can find the entire documentation here :
[c3p0 - JDBC3 Connection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html)